# Get element's offset position with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to make sure the page scrolls to an element when a certain span is clicked. So I need to check the element's `y` position. Can someone explain how I can get an element's position?

```
element.all(by.css('[scroll-to="section-executive-summary-anchor"]'))
  .then(function (elem) {
    elem[0].click().then(function () {
      element(by.id('section-executive-summary-anchor'))
        .then(function (el) {
          // I need "el.position" or something along those lines 
        });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`getLocation()` function](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getLocation):

```
element(by.id('section-executive-summary-anchor')).getLocation().then(function (location) {
    expect(location.y).toEqual(100);
});
```

Comment: This gets the relative location. How do you get the absolute location?